# Images of the stereographic projection's inverse

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve a problem which states:

Let $\phi: \bar{\mathbb C} \to S^2$ be the inverse function of the stereographic projection Calculate $\phi(Re(z))=0$ and $\phi(Im(z))=0$.

I can guess that $\phi(Re(z))=0$ is a circle in the $yz$ plane and the other one a circle in the $xz$ plane. I've tried to formally prove that the respective images are those but I couldn't.

I know that if $z=a+ib$, then $\phi(z)=(\dfrac{2Re(z)}{1+|z|^2},\dfrac{2Im(z)}{1+|z|^2},\dfrac{|z|^2-1}{1+|z|^2})$.

Take the first case, $\phi(Re(z))=0$ is equal to the points of the form $(0,\dfrac{2b^2}{1+b^4},\dfrac{b^4-1}{1+b^4})$. I also know that these points must lie in $S^2$, so $||(0,\dfrac{2b^2}{1+b^4},\dfrac{b^4-1}{1+b^4})||^2=1$

From these equation I got $b \in \{-1,0,1\}$, that doesn't make any sense.

What am I doing wrong and what could I do to properly describe the respective images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You performed the squaring earlier than it should have been used:

We have $Im(z)=b$ and $|z|^2=b^2$, and you took their squares.

With these, we get $\left(0,\displaystyle\frac{2b}{1+b^2},\frac{b^2-1}{1+b^2}\right)$, and we get it for *any* $b\in\Bbb R$. 
(Check that its norm will be always $1$).

Comment: What a fool!, I've already check its norm is 1. Thanks